# SQL: Joining two tables to find the first matching record within a subset

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have data which contains request/response messages. I have split it into two tables. Table t1 contains all requests and t2 contains all responses.
Frame indicates the frame number and time indicates the timestamp. Now I need to map the request to corresponding response message.

This is the query that I have currently and it works as intended.

```
SELECT t1.frame as frame1, min(t2.frame) as frame2, t1.key, 
(min(t2.time)-t1.time) as delta 
FROM t1 
JOIN t2 
ON t2.frame > t1.frame and 
t2.key LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.key, '%')
GROUP BY t1.frame, t1.time, t1.key 
ORDER BY t1.frame
```

What I am doing here is, for every record from `t1` (request message), find the **first** record in `t2` (response message) which is **after** `t1's` record (based on timestamp) and where the key from `t1` is present in `t2`. Then get the time difference between those 2 records.
Now it's doing exactly what it is supposed to do. But my problem is, there can be cases where response is missing (which is what I want to catch along with measuring the response time). So it might happen that:

```
1) Request for ID1<---
2) <No Response for ID1>  
3) Request for ID1<---
4) Response for ID1-->
```

The above query will report #4 as the response for both #1 and #3 which is not correct.
I want that for Request #1, it returns null or some string which I can then search and say how many requests were not responded.
Looks like I have to use multiple sub-queries. I am using **Apache Spark SQL** but this should be a generic SQL question.
Any help on this will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Sample data and results

```
t1:
frame, Time,  Key
1      2.3   0x01
4      3.5   0x02
13     4.6   0x03
22     6.2   0x03

t2:
frame, Time,  Key
3      2.5   0x01
8      3.8   0x02
25     6.3   0x03

Expected Result:
t1.frame, t2.frame,  delta, key
1         3          0.2    0x01
4         8          0.3    0x02
13        null       null   null
22        25         0.1    0x03
```

HTH

Comment: What if there are no responses for some requests due to timeouts or so? For example 4 request with the same ID have been sent but only 2 responses for these requests have been received?

Comment: Not sure I understood your question completely. These messages are internal messages between 2 components. There will be only 1 outstanding 'transaction' for a particular ID. So case of 4 request messages does not arise. So second request cannot come in until the first time has timed out, either due to no response or delayed response. Thanks.

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In generic SQL this can be achieved with help of LEFT JOIN 

and ANTI JOIN (`NOT EXISTS` operator together with correlated subquery), 
but I don't know whether they are supported by Spark SQL or not.

Demo: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/78432/2)

---

```
SELECT t1.frame as frame1, min(t2.frame) as frame2, t1.key, 
(min(t2.time)-t1.time) as delta 
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 
ON t2.frame > t1.frame 
   and t2.key LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.key, '%')
   and NOT EXISTS ( 
       SELECT 5 FROM t1 t11 
       WHERE t11.key = t1.key
         AND t11.time > t1.time
         AND t11.time < t2.time
   )
GROUP BY t1.frame, t1.time, t1.key 
ORDER BY t1.frame
```

---

Comment: Thanks I will try this.

Comment: Got following error. Looks like it is not supported in Spark SQL. :( `Predicate sub-queries can only be used in a Filter: 'Join LeftOuter, (((frame_number#25777 > frame_number#22147) && L1_FAPI_dlDCIPduInfo_st_rnti#26194 LIKE concat(%, L1_FAPI_srPduIndication_st_rnti#22410, %)) && NOT exists#25772).` I still have a way to detect this case since the column contains duplicate entries. However it would have been good if I could generate the results correctly the first time.

Comment: I will mark the answer since it does what I wanted it to do. Unfortunately Spark SQL doesn't seem to support it. Thanks for your help @krokodilko.

Comment: BTW, I did not understand what the SELECT 5 does. Can you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: Found this. [JIRA case](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14781).  `Right now, we does not support nested IN/EXISTS subquery, for example
EXISTS( x1) OR EXISTS( x2)
In order to do that, we could use an internal-only join type SemiPlus, which will output every row from left, plus additional column as the result of join condition. Then we could replace the EXISTS() or IN() by the result column.`

Comment: EXIST/NOT EXIST operators check for existence of rows in the resultset, but values are not relevant, so anything can be used in the SELECT list - *, 1, NULL, 5, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Would you know how to modify the query to use 'internal-only join type SemiPlus'?